# How can I modify a collection and set one field of the collection to a substring of a unique GUID?

Tags: c#

I have the following collection:

```
IList<Question> questionList;
```

Where question is like this:

```
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    ...
    public string QuestionUId { get; set; }
}
```

The questions in the collection have the value of QuestionUId set to null.

Is there some way I can modify this collection so the values are set to 
a value that is equal to the last six characters of a GUID?

Comment: A GUID? What GUID? Or do you mean a random GUID? Note that just because the GUID is unique doesn't mean that the last 6 characters will be unique... (Using 6 random characters as a unique ID seems an unfortunate choice to me. Given that you've got a integer question ID already, why do you need a string version too?)

Comment: I'm okay with the last six characters of a GUID. Yes I understand it won't be random but I have a unique non clustered index on that column and I'm okay if it fails once in a billion+ times. The QuestionUId is an alternate ID that I will use for maintenance / display purposes. What I am hoping for is a LINQ solution that could do this in one line without needing a for loop.

Comment: LINQ is for *querying* data. You're *changing* data. Just use a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have an `IList<Question>` instance you could always loop through the values and do whatever processing you like with them:

```
foreach (var item in questionList)
{
    Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    item.QuestionUId = guid.ToString().Substring(30);
}
```

But this won't guarantee you any uniqueness of those `QuestionUId` properties if that is what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if i got you.
Iterate over the list `foreach (Question question in questionList) {}` and alter value...